# PSFTP - File Transfer Not Happening

Tags: putty, psftp

I want a file to transfer automatically for one server to another server. For that i have installed putty.

Batch File: Transfer.Bat

```
cd "C:\Program Files\PuTTY"
psftp Username@RemoteServer.com -pw password -b MovementFileTransferScript.txt -be
```

Text File: MovementFileTransferScript.txt

```
open RemoteServer.com
put D:/Backup/FULL_DB_BACKUP-DontDelete.txt R:\DB\Backup
quit
```

In the above text file, D:/ belongs to Source Server and R:/ belongs to destination server.

When i am running the batch file i am getting the below error.

```
Using username "Username".
Remote working directory is /
psftp: already connected
local: unable to open D:/Backup/FULL_DB_BACKUP-DontDelete.txt
```

I have checked the permissions of the folders and everything looks good. Can some one let me know what was the issue here.?

Comment: So what if you do `type D:/Backup/FULL_DB_BACKUP-DontDelete.txt` in your batch file, just before you run `psftp`?

Comment: Tried this. D:/Backup/FULL_DB_BACKUP-DontDelete.txt
psftp Username@RemoteServer.com -pw password -b MovementFileTransferScript.txt -be -------> Still same issue.

Comment: What does it mean *"still the same issue"*? What does the `type` command do?

Comment: local: unable to open D:/Backup/FULL_DB_BACKUP-DontDelete.txt...this is am getting whenever i add the directory before psftp command.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how that answers my question.